# Shutdown service from QuartzJob

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net, topshelf

I use TopShelf for build windows service and TopShelf.Quartz package.
Is it possible to shutdown whole service from Execute method of IJob ? Right now all I can do is delete job. E.g if I catch specific exception in job I would like to make log and shutdown service.

Thanks for any answer.

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
     HostFactory.Run(c =>
     {
        // Topshelf.Ninject (Optional) - Initiates Ninject and consumes Modules
        c.UseNinject(new SampleModule());

        c.Service<SampleService>(s =>
        {
            //Topshelf.Ninject (Optional) - Construct service using Ninject
            s.ConstructUsingNinject();

            s.WhenStarted((service, control) => service.Start());
            s.WhenStopped((service, control) => service.Stop());

            // Topshelf.Quartz.Ninject (Optional) - Construct IJob instance with Ninject
            s.UseQuartzNinject(); 

            // Schedule a job to run in the background every 5 seconds.
            // The full Quartz Builder framework is available here.
            s.ScheduleQuartzJob(q =>
                q.WithJob(() =>
                    JobBuilder.Create<SampleJob>().Build())
                .AddTrigger(() =>
                    TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(builder => builder
                            .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                            .RepeatForever())
                        .Build())
                );
        });
    });
  }
}

public class SampleJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //Here I want catch exception and shoutdown service
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You name `context`, and you can get your scheduler and shutdown it

```
public class SampleJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        context.Scheduler.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

On [documentation](https://github.com/dtinteractive/Topshelf.Integrations) page there is example of stopping whole service (if i'm not mistaken):

```
c.Service<SampleService>(s =>
{
    //Specifies that Topshelf should delegate to Ninject for construction
    s.ConstructUsingNinject();

    s.WhenStarted((service, control) => service.Start());
    s.WhenStopped((service, control) => service.Stop());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want shutdown whole service not just Scheduler. I have no idea how to sent info from quartz to topshelf about that exception and shoutdown service

Comment: @Zabaa look at examples here https://github.com/dtinteractive/Topshelf.Integrations, it seems, last one is your case. also, updated answer

Comment: This, but make your service implement ServiceControl, and let Topshelf call those methods instead of using the delegates above. Then, when you want to stop, call HostControl.Stop(). HostControl is the argument for the Start method of ServiceControl.